# googletest SetUp Method not called

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm using [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) to unit test my C++ project. The getting started guide says:

> If necessary, write a default constructor or SetUp() function to prepare the objects for each test. A common mistake is to spell SetUp() as Setup() with a small u - don't let that happen to you.

`SetUp()` is spelled correctly, but I still can't get `SetUp` to work. Any ideas?

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class SampleTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  virtual void SetUp() { std::cout << "SetUp called." << std::endl; }
};

TEST(SampleTest, OneEqualsOne) {
  int one = 1;
  ASSERT_EQ(1, one);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

`g++ -g -Wno-deprecated -I gtest/include SampleTest.cpp gtest/libgtest.a -o SampleTest`

Output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from SampleTest
[ RUN      ] SampleTest.OneEqualsOne
[       OK ] SampleTest.OneEqualsOne (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from SampleTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `TEST` to `TEST_F`, as `SetUp` methods and such are called with `TEST_F`, but not with `TEST` alone.

Comment: When using google test adapter for visual studio, it does now allow me to change TEST to TEST_F. Any idea about that?

Comment: It might be a problem with using the right include files.

Answer (score 2):

Change your TEST macro to TEST_F.  (It's listing in the documentation right underneath the quote you provided.)

Comment: Thank you Ron! Indeed it is in the documentation. Looks like I missed that part. Link to the docs: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_Primer#Test_Fixtures:_Using_the_Same_Data_Configuration_for_Multiple_Te

Comment: New link to docs: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md